# Having Problems with Random Number Generator VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, enums

I am building a simple Tic Tac Toe Game and I ran into a problem. I am trying write a script for the computer to make a move in the game and I got stuck. Here is the part of my code that I am having trouble with.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Enum Buttons As Byte
        btn1 = 1
        btn2 = 2
        btn3 = 3
        btn4 = 4
        btn5 = 5
        btn6 = 6
        btn7 = 7
        btn8 = 8
        btn9 = 9
    End Enum

    Public Sub Computer(ByVal ButtonSelected As Button, ByVal Buttons As Buttons)
        Dim RandomNumberGenerator As New Random
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer
        RandomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 9)
        If Buttons.RandomNumber Then

        End If


    End Sub
```

The problem that I am having is with the If Statment. I want to use the random number to select a button from the Enum but I don't know how to. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You might want to look at a long tutorial on TDD in C# developing a Tic-Tac-Toe program.  It's by Derek Greer, and is at http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/tag/tdd/. I know, C# isn't VB.NET, but you might find it partially familiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a cast to convert the integer to an enum.  Also be sure to initialize the Random class object only once so you won't get the same button over and over again.  Like this:

```
Dim RandomNumberGenerator As New Random

Public Sub Computer()
    Dim RandomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 9)
    Dim RandomButton = CType(RandomNumber, Buttons)
    '' etc..
End Sub
```